# FlatList and ScrollView not scrolling with React Native Web when using React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-native-web, react-native-scrollview

Pushing a screen of a React Navigation Stack with a FlatList will break the scrolling support on Web.

Tried several suggested solutions - none of these worked:

- Including a parent View with flex property `style={{flex: 1}}`
- Replacing FlatList with a ScrollView

What worked for me was adding a flex property to `cardStyle` in `screenOptions` of the React Navigation stack navigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator mode="card" screenOptions={{ cardStyle: { flex: 1 } }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="MyScreen" component={MyScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding a flex property to `cardStyle` in `screenOptions` of the React Navigation stack navigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator mode="card" screenOptions={{ cardStyle: { flex: 1 } }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="MyScreen" component={MyScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

See also:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6165

Comment: Thank you for this question and answer, been searching for the solution for ages

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and spent an age trying to find the source. I had a FlatList which assumed was the to blame... but the error remained even after commenting out.... after much cache flushing... I traced the problem to having a native base Select inside a native base Modal.